# Getting the address of a statically allocated array into a pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

The simplified version of my code is the following:

```
struct args {
    int p;
    int *A;
};

typedef struct sort_args sort_args;

void func(int A[], int p) 
{
    args new_struct = {&A, p};
    args *args_ptr = &new_struct;
}
```

I'm trying to convert a statically (I think that's the term) allocated array into a pointer, but the compiler keeps throwing these warnings:

> warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]
>        args new_struct = {&A, p, r};
>
> warning: (near initialization for ‘new_struct.p’) [enabled by default]
>   warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   [enabled by default] warning: (near initialization for ‘new_struct.A’)
>   [enabled by default]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the parameters backwards.

```
args new_struct = {&A, p};
```

=>

```
args new_struct = {p, A};
```

You need to initialize the members of a struct in exactly the same order as they appear in the structs declaration, or you need to use named syntax like this:

```
args new_struct = { .A = A, .p = p };
```

But this is usually only used to improve code clarity with larger structs who have more members.

Comment: I had switched A to the end of the struct and forgotten to switch the order in the initialization line. Thank you!